# Phantom iCal calendar subscriptions won't go away after deleting and iCal missing from Mobile.me

Tags: ical

I had subscribed to my meetup.com calendar via iCal and after a week decided to delete the calendar subscription by right clicking on the subscribed calendar name and clicking delete.  However, I still get popups to add events to my calendar for meetup even after I deleted it.

I thought I'd resysnc my data from Mobile.me and overwrite my calendar data on my mac with the data from Mobile.me and the calendar data doesn't even appear in the Mobile.me preferences, though everything else seems to still be there.

Has anyone else had this problem and know how to:
get the phantom calendars to go away forever
get iCal to re-appear in Mobile.me sync preferences

-- Brian

Answer (score 1):

This got answered for me on https://discussions.apple.com/message/15816044#15816044

Turns out that it wasn't enough to delete the calendar in iCal, I also had to change a setting at meetup.com.